# Preventing squeaky floor

Tags: foundation, joists, construction, renovation, squeak

We had a major house fire and our house has been demo'd down to the frame.  The floor is 2x12 x 8 long joists that butt against each other on the cross beam supports.  We plan on using adhesive on the joists for the plywood subfloors

What can i include additionally to reduce squeaky floors while we have the entire foundation exposed?  For example where joists butt against each other or where they rest against each other?  Is there a thin epoxy that will seep between the joints or maybe just screw the crap out of everything?

Thanks!

Comment: i've found the opposite of gluing can help; liquid hand soap applied to the moving parts seeps into the friction points and makes a big difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing what's standard in modern construction. Squeaks are almost always due to something oriented *crosswise* to the joist flexing, or to fasteners that partially miss the joist. The adhesive helps with that for the subfloor. Use a 3/8" bead to ensure a good bond and that gaps are filled well. Be sure to catch both edges in butt joints.

Joists don't usually cause noise against each other. I wouldn't worry about that unless you're aware of a specific troublesome case. The can't really move in such a way as to create noise. When in doubt, more adhesive can't hurt.

The next most common source of noise is utility equipment. Look for anything added to the framing after it was installed:

- Ductwork and supports
- Plumbing supports
- Overly tight plumbing penetrations

Finally, look at wall plates on the subfloor. I've seen them squeak in new homes where they're nailed down between joists, and subfloor flex results in nail squeaks. Add screws if needed to lock things in place.